# trouble using wsapi store filtering features by release set in context timebox

Tags: rally

I'm trying to create a custom html app in rally. In the page where the app will be added, I have a filter for release. I want to create a list of features for the release selected by the user. It looks like I should be able to match the _ref field of the release selected by the user to the Release._ref for the features by defining a filter in the store for the features. I think it's not working because some features don't have a release defined so when the filter attempts to check Release._ref, Release is null and therefore throws a null reference error. This seems like a very basic thing to do. What is the right way to do this?

snipit of code I think is important:

```
console.log('_loadData');
    var timeBoxScope = this.getContext().getTimeboxScope().record.data._ref; // only works in Rally for custom page with Release filter
    console.log('timebox', timeBoxScope);

    var myStore = Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.Store', {
    model: 'PortfolioItem/Feature',
    pageSize: 10,
    autoLoad: true,
    fetch: ['FormattedID', 'Name', 'Owner', 'Release', 'UserStories'],
    filters: [
    {
        property: 'Release._ref',
        operator: '=',
        value: timeBoxScope
         }],
    listeners: {
```

whole thing i'm working on:

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
extend: 'Rally.app.App',
componentCls: 'app',
launch: function () {
    console.log('launch');
    this._loadData();
},
// load rally data
_loadData: function () {
    console.log('_loadData');
    var timeBoxScope = this.getContext().getTimeboxScope().record.data._ref; // only works in Rally for custom page with Release filter
    console.log('timebox', timeBoxScope);

    var myStore = Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.Store', {
    model: 'PortfolioItem/Feature',
    pageSize: 10,
    autoLoad: true,
    fetch: ['FormattedID', 'Name', 'Owner', 'Release', 'UserStories'],
    filters: [
    {
        property: 'Release._ref',
        operator: '=',
        value: timeBoxScope
         }],
    listeners: {
        load: function(store, data){
            var features = [];
            var pendingstories = data.length;
            //debugger;
            Ext.Array.each(data, function(feature) {
                        var f  = {
                            FormattedID: feature.get('FormattedID'),
                            Name: feature.get('Name'),
                            _ref: feature.get("_ref"),
                            Owner: feature.get("Owner")._refObjectName,
                            StoryCount: feature.get('UserStories').Count,
                            UserStories: []
                        };
console.log('feature', feature);
console.log('feature release', feature.data.Release._ref);
                        var stories = feature.getCollection('UserStories');
                       stories.load({
                            fetch: ['FormattedID'],
                            callback: function(records, operation, success){
                                Ext.Array.each(records, function(story){
                                    var number = story.get('DirectChildrenCount');  
                                    if (number == 0) {
                                        f.UserStories.push({_ref: story.get('_ref'),
                                                    FormattedID: story.get('FormattedID')
                                                });}
                                }, this);

                                --pendingstories;
                                if (pendingstories === 0) {
                                    this._createGrid(features);
                                }
                            },
                            scope: this
                        });
                        features.push(f);
            }, this);
},
        scope: this
    }
});
},
_createGrid: function(features) {
     this.add({
        xtype: 'rallygrid',
        store: Ext.create('Rally.data.custom.Store', {
            data: features,
            pageSize: 100
        }),

        columnCfgs: [
            {
               text: 'Formatted ID', dataIndex: 'FormattedID', xtype: 'templatecolumn',
                tpl: Ext.create('Rally.ui.renderer.template.FormattedIDTemplate')
            },
            {
                text: 'Name', dataIndex: 'Name'
            },
            {
                text: 'Owner', dataIndex: 'Owner'
            },
            {
                text: 'Story Count', dataIndex: 'StoryCount'
            },
            {
                text: 'User Stories', dataIndex: 'UserStories', 
                renderer: function(value) {
                    var html = [];
                    Ext.Array.each(value, function(userstory){
                        html.push('<a href="' + Rally.nav.Manager.getDetailUrl(userstory) + '">' + userstory.FormattedID + '</a>');
                    });
                    return html.join(', ');
                }
            }
        ]

    });
}
```

}
);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself. As I suspected, I was doing it wrong. Here is how to setup the filter. See the definition of 'filters' below:

```
var timeBoxScope = this.getContext().getTimeboxScope();//.record.data._ref; // only works in Rally for custom page with Release filter
    console.log('timebox', timeBoxScope);
var myStore = Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.Store', {
    model: 'PortfolioItem/Feature',
    pageSize: 10,
    autoLoad: true,
    fetch: ['FormattedID', 'Name', 'Owner', 'Release', 'UserStories'],
    filters: timeBoxScope.getQueryFilter(),
    listeners: {
```